# Trouble passing SQL data to view in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, view, controller

I have a form that I am using to allow people to input data and then upload a preset picture. I want to label that picture as the form_id. I am able to run a LAST_INSERT_ID() query and display it after I insert the form in my view but I can't seem to echo that information out anywhere else. I need the query to select_last_id to run after my $update query or the ID number will be off. Could anyone assist in helping me pass just the value of the row to my view? Here is the code from my controller.

```
function inspection() {

    if($this->input->post('submit')) {
        $array = array(

            'trlr_num' => $this->input->post('trlr_num'),
            'seal' => $this->input->post('seal'),
            'damaged' => $this->input->post('damaged'),
            'truck_num' => $this->input->post('truck_num'),
            'driver_name' => $this->input->post('driver_name'),
            'car_code' => $this->input->post('car_code'),
            'origin' => $this->input->post('origin'),
            'lic_plate' => $this->input->post('lic_plate'),
            'del_note' => $this->input->post('del_note'),
            'live_drop' => $this->input->post('live_drop'),
            'temp' => $this->input->post('temp'),
            'level' => $this->input->post('level'),
            'ship_num' => $this->input->post('ship_num'),
            'trlr_stat' => $this->input->post('trlr_stat'),
            'comment' => $this->input->post('comment')

                        );
        $update = $this->trailer_model->insert_form($array);

        $query = $this->trailer_model->select_last_id();
        $result =& $query->result_array();

        $this->table->set_heading('ID');
        $data['table'] = $this->table->generate_table($result);
        unset($query,$result);


       }
    $level = $this->trailer_model->select_fuel_level();
    $result = $level->result_array();

    $data['options'] = array();
    foreach($result as $key => $row) {
        $data['options'][$row['level']] = $row['level'];
    }
    unset($query,$result,$key,$row);

    $data['label_display'] = 'Fuel Level';
    $data['field_name'] = 'level';

    $status = $this->trailer_model->select_trailer_type();
    $result = $status->result_array();

    $data['options1'] = array();
    foreach($result as $key => $row) {
        $data['options1'][$row['trlr_stat']] = $row['trlr_stat'];
    }
    unset($query,$result,$key,$row);


    $data['label_display1'] = 'Trailer Status';
    $data['field_name1'] = 'trlr_stat';


    $data['page_title'] = 'Trailer Inspection';
    $data['main_content'] = 'dlx/inspection/trailer_inspection_view';


    return $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you want to display on a view, you must pass to it.

When you're setting `$data`, you missed adding `$query` to it.

**Controller:**

I understand that `$query = $this->trailer_model->select_last_id();` is returning just an ID, so:

`$data['last_id'] = $query;`

But if `$query = $this->trailer_model->select_last_id();` **does not** return just an ID, but an array or something else, you shall include to return the ID in your model method. Actually, it'd be crucial to know what `$this->trailer_model->select_last_id();` is returning.

**View:**

`echo $last_id;` -> must echo the last ID, if `select_last_id()` method from your model returns what it has to return.